# Unable to resolve typescript error for redux createSlice

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

THis is my code:

```js
import { Conversation } from "@/types/conversation";
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState: Conversation | null = null;

export const conversationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "conversation",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setConversation: ( // type error
      state: Conversation | null,
      action: PayloadAction<Conversation>
    ) => {
      state = action.payload;
      return state;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setConversation } = conversationSlice.actions;

export default conversationSlice.reducer;
```

THis is the error I am receiving:

```
Type '(state: Conversation | null, action: PayloadAction<Conversation>) => Conversation' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<null, { payload: any; type: string; }> | CaseReducerWithPrepare<null, PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>>'.
  Type '(state: Conversation | null, action: PayloadAction<Conversation>) => Conversation' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<null, { payload: any; type: string; }>'.
    Type 'Conversation' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)
```

I know that immer is used under the hood of `createSlice`. WHen I remove return statement from `setCOnversation` - error is gone but reducer does not work. If I leave it like that, reducer works (organization sets) but I have an error.

How to fix it ?

I have tried to get rid of return statement, but it brokes application in the other way. ALso read redux toolkit docs

Still getting an error:

```js
import { Draft, PayloadAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface Conversation {
  any_data: string[];
}
const initialState: Conversation | null = null;

export const conversationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "conversation",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setConversation: (
      // type error
      state: Draft<Conversation | null>,
      action: PayloadAction<Conversation>
    ) => action.payload,
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setConversation } = conversationSlice.actions;

export default conversationSlice.reducer;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqqEjm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot ***reassign*** state in RTK reducers, e.g. `state = action.payload` is invalid. You can either ***mutate*** the draft state *or* ***return*** the new state value (***never both***).

I'd argue that the `conversation` state ***should not*** be nullable. With nullable state the UI would need to first check that the state is defined, e.g. not null. I suggest dropping the nullable state and make the conversation state properties optional. The UI will then use a null-check on the conversation state property it accesses.

Consider the following rewrite:

```js
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface Conversation {
  any_data?: string[];
}
const initialState: Conversation = {};

export const conversationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "conversation",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setConversation: (state, action: PayloadAction<Conversation>) => {
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setConversation } = conversationSlice.actions;

export default conversationSlice.reducer;
```